RTL8821CE driver for Ubuntu 24.04 is not working
installed Ubuntu 24.04 on a laptop and there is no Wifi option. After installing the tomaspinho/rtl8821ce via dkms I keep running into the *-network UNCLAIMED error:
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:a1100000-a110ffff

The driver seems to be installed properly after reboot, however it just doesn't do anything.
rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 6.8.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed

I disabled Secure Boot and Fast Boot with no results. Bluetooth and tethering are working though.
Additional information on the driver:
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter


Plessis edit to include results from terminal for grep [[:alnum:]] /etc/modprobe.d/* | grep 8821

I would guess if you run sudo modprobe rtw88_8821ce in terminal that wifi would work, the command I posted as a comment will reveal why it doesn't work on its own
