No Wi-Fi after upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I have a notebook HP 250 G7 wit Intel® Core™ i3-7020U × 4 processor.
Wi-Fi connection worked perfectly with former Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS version , Network controller: Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter .
After upgrade to 24.04.1 LTS the Wi-Fi-connection-icon in top right corner of the screen does not appear, I only see "Wired" , "Tether", "Bluetooth","Power Mode","Night-light", "Dark style", "Airplane mode".
In terminal mode when I input the command lspci -v , under Network controller Realtek etc. I read "Capabilities: access denied
Why ???
What can I do ??

https://laptopmedia.com/laptop-specs/hp-250-g7/  I think you are running with product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (Please correct if I am wrong.)  'sudo lsmod | grep 802' or 'sudo lsmod | grep RTL8821' See link for similar problem https://askubuntu.com/questions/1525513/rtl8821ce-driver-for-ubuntu-24-04-is-not-working

I input  'sudo lsmod | grep 802' , answer is : Command 'smod not found, did you mean:  '  and a list of other suggested commands like smsd smbd, kmod , mod, jmod,  smcd,  qmod, lsmod...

Append to your post the result of 'sudo lspci -v' & 'sudo lshw -C network'

Any results from terminal for dkms status

sorry David , I see no way to append 8 screenshots of my terminal after sudo lspci -v or sudo lshw -c network

no result from dkms status

frankly speaking, I expected this problem to be fixed by Ubuntu, given that so many people have my same problem

ALSO after inputting sudo modprobe rtw88_8821ce I get answer ' modprobe : FATAL: Module rtw_8821ce not found in directory /lib/modules/6.8.0-45-generic '
what else can I do to have wifi connection ?

after inputting again today sudo modprobe rtw88_8821ce I could connect to my wi-fi .

TODAY , AGAIN, PC CONNECTION TO WI-FI IS NOT AVAILABLE !  what can i do ???

at present I must input " sudo modprobe rtw88_8821ce " every time I turn my PC on in order to enable wifi connection .  Is there a way to memorize this activation ?

Anyway, thanks to  Jeremy31 for his suggestion to another Ubuntuer, I survive with  inputting "sudo modprobe rtw88_8821ce " by any start-up , although I'd like to stabilize the wi-fi start-up
